# Need help in plotting lines between points

Tags: matlab

I need help in plotting lines between points.
Suppose, I start with creating 6 random points-

```
x = rand(6,1);
y = rand(6,1);
```

So my points are `(x(1),y(1)), (x(2),y(2)), (x(3),y(3)), (x(4),y(4)), (x(5),y(5)), (x(6),y(6))`

Now I want to draw straight lines between the points 1 & 5, 2 & 6, 3 & 4
and plot them in a single diagram. So I get 3 straight lines.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one call to [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html). If you reshape your `x` and `y` data into matrices with each column containing a set of coordinates for one line, then [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) will draw a different colored line for each column:

```
index = [1 2 3; 5 6 4];   %# The index to reshape x and y into 2-by-3 matrices
plot(x(index),y(index));  %# Plot the lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do this:

First way, using `hold on`. These lines are separate, i.e if you turn one red, the others will stay blue.

```
%# plot the first line
plot([x(1);x(5)],[y(1);y(5)]);

hold on %# this will prevent the previous plot from disappearing

%# plot the rest
plot([x(2);x(6)],[y(2);y(6)]);
plot([x(3);x(4)],[y(3);y(4)]);
```

Second way, making use of the fact that `NaN` does not get plotted. These lines are grouped, i.e. if you turn one red, all will be red.

```
%# create array for plotting
xy = NaN(8,2);

%# fill in data
xy([1 2 4 5 7 8],1) = x([1 5 2 6 3 4]);
xy([1 2 4 5 7 8],2) = y([1 5 2 6 3 4]);

%# plot
plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2))
```